# If $f$ is continuous and satisfies $|f(x) - f(y)| \ge \log(1+|x-y|)$, how do I show that $f$ is bijective?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge \log(1+|x-y|)$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R$. Prove that $f$ is bijective.

$f(x)=f(y)$ at once implies $x=y$ and hence $f$ is injective. How do I prove surjectivity?

Comment: Hint: prove that it is monotonic

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f $ is continuous at $ I= (-\infty,+\infty) $, therefore $ f(I) $ is an intervall $ J$

But

$$(\forall x\in I) \;\; |f(x)-f(0)|\ge \ln(1+|x|)$$

and
$$\lim_{|x|\to \infty}\ln(1+|x|)=+\infty.$$
implies that
$$\lim_{|x|\to \infty}|f(x)|=+\infty.$$
You proved that $ f $ is injective. thus
$$f(I)=(-\infty,+\infty)=\Bbb R$$
which shows that $ f $ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am not sure if I see how $\lim_{x\to \infty}|f(x)|=\infty$ guarantees that the range is $\Bbb{R}$. What if $f>0$, injective  and goes to infinity (like $f(x)=e^x$)?

Comment: @AnuragA Do not forget that $ f$ is continuous and injective. Both limits at $+$ and $-\infty$ are infinite.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah please see my edited comment, $e^x$ has all the attributes you have stated: it is continuous, injective and $|e^x|$ goes to infinity but the function is positive so range is not $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @AnuragA No, here the limit at minus infinity is zero, not infinity.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah you have shown it for $\lim_{x \to +\infty}$ and not $\lim_{x \to -\infty}$.

Comment: @AnuragA No, here the limit at minus infinity is zero, not infinity.

Comment: @AnuragA No, for both, when $|x|$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah okay GOOD that now you have **edited** your answer to include $|x|$ as opposed to just $x$, which is fine. Because otherwise your conclusion would have been incorrect.

Comment: @AnuragA Thank you very much for your plaisant remarks.

Comment: (-1) @AnuragA [hamam_Abdallah](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/369188/hamam-abdallah) still did not prove surjectivity. His remarks are not sufficient. There is a huge gap from "$\lim_{|x|\to \infty}|f(x)|=+\infty.$ You proved that $ f $ is injective." to "thus
$f(I)=(-\infty,+\infty)=\Bbb R$". Luckily, there are true answers in [several duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4615446/386889).